# Magento CSV Import Images Missing

Tags: mysql, magento, csv, import, magento-1.7

I edited my products by exporting them with the Import/Export Tool in magento, after I imported them I got faced with There was a problem with reindexing process, which I finally fixed.

But now all my images are missing and not displaying in the front end, can someone help me fix this issue?

/1/_/1_7_138.jpg is the format that the CSV images locations are

I also tried moving the images in media/category/product to media/import but still not displaying correctly

I also tried editing file permissions from 755 to 77 in the media folder but still nothing

I also ran this in the corresponding SQL database

```
INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_media_gallery (attribute_id, entity_id, `value`)
SELECT ga.attribute_id, v.entity_id, v.value
FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar v
INNER JOIN eav_entity_type et ON et.entity_type_code=\'catalog_product\'
INNER JOIN eav_attribute va ON va.entity_type_id=et.entity_type_id AND
va.frontend_input=\'media_image\' AND va.attribute_id=v.attribute_id
INNER JOIN eav_attribute ga ON va.entity_type_id=et.entity_type_id AND
ga.attribute_code=\'media_gallery\'
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_media_gallery g ON g.entity_id=v.entity_id AND
g.value=v.value
WHERE v.value<>\'no_selection\' AND v.value<>\'\' AND g.value IS NULL;
```

and got the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'catalog_product\' INNER JOIN
eav_attribute va ON va.entity_ty
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're having the same problem that I did, but when I re-imported products my images broke **but** the image was still associated with the product, just not set as the base, small, thumbnail, etc

I did something like

```
update catalog_product_entity_varchar AS v inner join catalog_product_entity_media_gallery AS g on v.entity_id = g.entity_id set v.value = g.value where (v.attribute_id = '85' or v.attribute_id = '86' or v.attribute_id = '87');
```

in my database to reassign them all.

Comment: yea I am having the same issue and they aren't showing up in the backend at all should I run this code in phpmyadmin in the proper MySQL Database?

Comment: and in the front end they aren't set to base image

Answer (score 0):

Check following in

data base table  `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`  is there an entry for image you are looking for.

something like 1    703     17  /1/_/1_7_138.jpg

Then go to media/catalog/product/1/_/  and check if this image file exists.

Additional flush your cache and check.

Answer (score 0):

When using Import/Export, the folder structure in your media/import folder has to be the same as specified in your csv file. So if a media filename is specified as "/1/_/1_7_138.jpg" in your CSV, there *must* exist a file "/media/import/1/_/1_7_138.jpg" in your Magento root. Otherwise Import/Export won't find the media file.

The easiest solution would be, to not define a folder structure in your csv and to put all media files, that should be imported, directly in media/import/. So in your case:

**CSV entry** (e.g. in column 'thumbnail'): 1_7_138.jpg

**File**: /media/import/1_7_138.jpg

Unfortunately, Magento is not capable of importing its own exports! So an exported CSV has to be modified, to be importable in another Magento installation.

Comment: Okay one other question since the images are all in folders do I have to put the images into media/import or would it be okay to put /media/import/1/_/1_7_138.jpg

Comment: I tried moving all the media files  /media/import/1/_/1_7_138.jpg  in that format and all the images disappeared. But when I move them back to media/category/product they show up in the front end but just no default image, but they are still missing in the backend

Comment: /media/import/1/_/1_7_138.jpg would be ok. but the path in the csv file must be /1/_/1_7_138.jpg for that image. you do not have to move the files from media/catalog/product to the media/import folder. the media/import folder is just the place magento looks for images to import. when the import is running, magento creates the subdirectories at media/catalog/product/ and copies the images from media/import to these directories automatically

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still having issues, but to help with the INSERT query you listed, it's not working because the single quotes are escaped. I'm guessing you found this query in a post somewhere and when the query was posted, the single quotes were escaped with "\'".

If you change all of the \' to just single quotes like this:

INSERT INTO ......
INNER JOIN eav_entity_type et ON et.entity_type_code='catalog_product' <-- is where I changed the \' to just a single '. You'll need to do that with the entire query.

The query should then work. I also suggest as good practice, that you first run the select without the insert command to make sure it gives back good results before running an insert command blindly.